# "Resetear" valor de un EditText cuando es inválido en Android usando Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, edittext

Quisiera evaluar el texto de un edittext cuando el usuario introduzca o borre un texto. La cuestión es que el campo nunca puede estar vacío y además, si introduce algún valor erróneo, el campo debe mostrar el valor 0.

He intentado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido, pero no entiendo por qué al cambiar el valor del texto, peta mi aplicación. Supongo que el problema está en el AfterChange, aunque no sé exactamente cuál es.

Aquí dejo todo el códigio completo

```kotlin
package es.iessaladillo.pedrojoya.exchange

import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import es.iessaladillo.pedrojoya.exchange.databinding.MainActivityBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    /*
        Variable de acceso global a la vista, con las diferentes vistas.
     */
    private lateinit var binding: MainActivityBinding

    /*
        Determina la acción cuando el texto del EditText es cambiado
     */
    private lateinit var etxtAmountTextWatcher: TextWatcher

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Inicialización de binding y posterior inflado de la vista raíz.
        binding = MainActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setupFields()
        setupViews()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        binding.etxtMainAmount.addTextChangedListener(etxtAmountTextWatcher)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        binding.etxtMainAmount.removeTextChangedListener(etxtAmountTextWatcher)
    }

    private fun setupFields() {

        etxtAmountTextWatcher = object: TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {


                validAmount(s.toString(), binding.etxtMainAmount)
            }

        }
    }

    private fun setupViews() {
    }

    private fun validAmount(textToValidate: String, editText: EditText) {

        if(textToValidate.isBlank()) {
            editText.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("0")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comparte el log a ver qué error te da

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la respuesta al final.

En esta parte del código

```
override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
```

El TODO es una función...

Gracias!